# mysql error when attempting to run rspec suite

Tags: mysql, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ubuntu-11.04

Since I upgraded to rails 3.1 I've been getting this error on one of my projects when I try to run the specs for it, but only this one project, other rspec suites still run fine:

`ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in 'query': Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111): SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)`

This also crashes a script/runner I have going in another terminal.

I've tried updating these mysql vars: max_connections, key_buffer, max_allowed_packet, table_cache, sort_buffer_size, read_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size, myisam_sort_buffer_size, thread_cache_size, query_cache_size. And I manually set foreign key checks to 0.

On the rails side I've tried editing my database.yml so that reconnect is true and timeout is an insanely large number, nothing seems to help.